# Does vaex data frame doesn't support data generation

Tags: bigdata, data-generation, vaex

i have a dataset with schema,

| BIKE_ID | REGN_NUMBER | ENGINE_NUMBER | CHASSIS_NUMBER | BUYED_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XN67TY567 | 34567ABGN65 | 145089 | 2011 |
| 2 | XN67TM567 | 34567ABGT65 | 145085 | 2011 |
| 3 | XN67TM569 | 34567VBGT65 | 1450867 | 2013 |
| . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . |
| 2870763 | XN56RTMN | 34786VHGT65 | 14501236 | 2016 |

**Now i would like to generate the data from 28,70,764 to some 3,28,70,764 i.e generating around 30 Million rows**
so as in pandas we can use the below method.

```
val = 2870764
df3['POLICY_ID'] = range(val ,val+30000000)
```

but as it is huge data pandas can't generate, so is there any approach to solve this problem by doing it in Vaex.

But Vaex throws me an error
**ValueError: range(2870764, 5870764) is not of string or Expression type, but <class 'range'>**

So, could anyone suggest me whether can we do in this way in **Vaex**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, vaex has a function called `vrange` that does exactly what you're looking for, with no memory usage.

Example:

```
import vaex

df = vaex.example()
df
```

Here is a dataframe with 330,000 rows (using the example dataset at the time of writing). We can generate a new column, `POLICY_ID` using `vaex.vrange`

```
df["POLICY_ID"] = vaex.vrange(0, len(df))
```

vrange docs: https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.vrange